# Using concatMap in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Could you explain me how I could use concatMap on getPrices() and getDetails()?

```
   export class HistoricalPricesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
    
        infoTitle: string = "";
        lines: HistoryPoint[] = [];
    
        model: Currency = new Currency();
        svm: string;
    
        constructor(
            private location: Location,
            private service: HistoricalPricesService,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
        ) {}
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
            let svm: string | null;
            svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
            if (!svm) {
                this.goBack();
                return;
            }
            this.svm = svm;
    
    
            this.getPrices();
            this.getDetails(svm)
        }
    
        ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.unsubscribe$.next();
            this.unsubscribe$.complete();
        }
    
        getPrices(): void {
            this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(this.svm, this.model).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
            ).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                    if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
                        this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        getDetails(svm: string): void {
            this.service.getInstrumentInfo(svm).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
            ).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                    this.infoTitle += " " + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.LABEL + " (" + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.PLACELABEL + ")";
                }
            });
        }
    
        goBack(): void {
            this.location.back();
        }
    }
```

I tried to look on this page

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/using-concatmap-in-angular/

But I don't know where to start?

The example does not allow me to understand how I could create this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is
`concatMap` is a operator stream so you just need to use it through a creator stream to that I initialize two Subject for each actions `getPrices` & `getDetails`.

Then I perform the AJAX call following the concatMap strategy and get that into Observable in order to be combined or used directly into the template of the component.

```
   export class HistoricalPricesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();
    
        infoTitle: string = "";
        lines: HistoryPoint[] = [];
    
        model: Currency = new Currency();
        svm: string;
    
        // actions
        getPrices$ = new Subject<void>();
        getDetails$ = new Subject<string>();
        
        // states
        prices$: Observable<any>();
        details$: Observable<any>();
        
        constructor(
            private location: Location,
            private service: HistoricalPricesService,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
        ) {}
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
            let svm: string | null;
            svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
            if (!svm) {
                this.goBack();
                return;
            }
            this.svm = svm;
    
            this.prices$ = this.getPrices$.pipe(concatMap(this.getPrices)
            this.details$ = this.getDetails$.pipe(concatMap((svm => this.getDetails(svm))
    
        }
    
        ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.getPrices$.complete()
            this.getDetails$.complete()
            this.unsubscribe$.complete();
        }
    
        getPrices(): void {
            this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(this.svm, this.model).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
            ).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                    if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
                        this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        getDetails(svm: string): void {
            this.service.getInstrumentInfo(svm).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
            ).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                    this.infoTitle += " " + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.LABEL + " (" + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.PLACELABEL + ")";
                }
            });
        }
    
        goBack(): void {
            this.location.back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and why, so people can actually learn from it.

Comment: Thank you for your the explanations and the help.

Comment: Are you concating two observables here? Why is concatMap strategy useful here if both are independent?

Comment: @Harshal it's indeed a false friend concatMap is high-order Observable and the strategy of it consist to have a FIFO strategy so if you call it third times it wait the first end to trig the second and so on